# How to allow download url redirection for only logged-in wordpress users?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, session, redirect

I'm setting up a download redirection of external direct download links for not to show them inside wordpress for even logged-in members and also do not get them access to redirected download links if they are outside of wp. So basically

The direct download links (on perl based script on external site which i have control) are like:
`external.com/directdownload-34j5hjhj54/file1.html`
or
`external.com/directdownload-87897kk78/file2.html`
or
..... etc.
And i will replace all those links with `example.com/dl/34j5hjhj54/file21.html`

To do this, I've firstly put "/dl/" redirect to download.php in htaccess:

Secondly, added below code into download.php:

1) on .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dl$ /download.php [L]
```

2) on download.php

```
//load WP without theme support or hooks etc.

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

require('./wp-load.php'); //location of this file may be different 



if(get_current_user_id()){

    //user has valid WP login session

    header('Location: {https://external.com/directdownload-}');

}else{

    //user is not logged in

    header('Location: {/wp-login.php}');

}

exit; //just because
```

or
this code on download.php:

```
require('../wp-load.php');  // modify to reflect where your PHP file is in relation to Wordpress
$roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;  // get current users role

if (!in_array('alloweduserrole',$roles)) {  // modify to match your roles that are allowed to download

    header('Location: http://www.ourwebsite.com/');
    exit;

}  // end of if user does not have the proper role
```

I've expected for logged-in members to redirect https://external.com/directdownload- links and non logged-in members to redirect wp-login.php but nothing happened, both of them goes "page not found" actually. How to fix? Which code should i have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the top of you `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^dl(.*)$ /download.php$1 [L]
```

This would be the download.php content:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once './wp-load.php';
if ( !function_exists( 'is_user_logged_in' ) ) {
    require_once './wp-includes/pluggable.php';
}

if( is_user_logged_in() ){

    //user is logged in
    $location = end(explode('dl/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $location = ltrim($location, '/');
    wp_redirect( 'https://external.com/directdownload-' . $location );
    exit;

}else{

    //user is not logged in
    wp_redirect( home_url('/wp-login.php') );
    exit;

}

exit; //just because
?>
```

This is tested code, `.htaccess` will rewrite request on /dl/ to download.php and the latter will extract anything from the url after /dl/ and adds it to final redirect link after checking if user is logged in, if not logged it will redirect to login page.

Comment: very appreciate with your help, can you tell me why the post i edited before still has "/" for download link? and even i re-save it , it doesnt fix, its just one post..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand

Comment: can i replace if( is_user_logged_in() ) with   if (current_user_can("access_s2member_level2"))  ???

Comment: yeah if users have this capability

Comment: ok, how can i implement a google analytics to track those downloads? i cant see these redirect urls clicked on "user explorer" in g analytics.